# ORA-00984: column not allowd here on procedure with input variables

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00984

I seem to get ORA-00984 error when inserting the inputs to the sql statment

PLSQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_insättning (pnr_in in insättning.pnr%type, 
                                       knr_in in insättning.knr%type,
                                       belopp_in in insättning.belopp%type,
                                       datum_in in insättning.datum%type)
IS 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO insättning 
 VALUES (radnr_seq,pnr_in,knr_in,belopp_in,datum_in);
END;
```

The design of the table:
[image: Table design]

Also the radnr_seq:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE radnr_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

What I have tried is to check is that the sql statemtn only inserts to one column like this:

```
INSERT INTO insättning (radnr) values (radnr_seq);
```

Aswell as checking for invalid values but to no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call nextval for sequence :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_insättning (pnr_in in insättning.pnr%type, 
                                   knr_in in insättning.knr%type,
                                   belopp_in in insättning.belopp%type,
                                   datum_in in insättning.datum%type)
IS 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO insättning 
 VALUES (radnr_seq.NEXTVAL,pnr_in,knr_in,belopp_in,datum_in);
END;
```

Comment: Oh that's right, beginner mistake (I will accept once the timelimit has passed)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to insert the sequence number nextval `radnr_seq.nextval`.